# How do I access a hyperlink control that's in a gridview from _RowEditing Sub?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've run into a wall and could use some advice. I have a gridview that contains a "Details" hyperlink on each row. While I am in edit mode (inline), I want to disable the details link. I thought this would be simple, but I can't seem to make it work. I had assumed (wrongly) that I could do something like:

```
Dim lnkDetails As HyperLink = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lnkDetails"), HyperLink)
lnkDetails.Enabled = False
```

The problem here, as I found out, is the "e As GridViewEditEventArgs" part of my Sub doesn't include "Row".

Here is the relevant code:

```
Protected Sub gvCurRecords_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
        ' Make the GridView control into edit mode for the selected row.  
        gvCurRecords.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex

        ' Rebind the GridView control to show data in edit mode. 
        BindGridView()

        ' Hide the Add button. 
        lbtnAdd.Visible = False
End Sub
```

HTML (Only the relevant column):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCurRecords" CellPadding="4" DataSourceId="SqlDataSource1" 
        Autogeneratecolumns="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" OnRowEditing="gvCurRecords_RowEditing"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="gvCurRecords_RowCancelingEdit"
        OnRowUpdating="gvCurRecords_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="eventID" 
        OnRowDataBound="gvCurRecords_RowDataBound" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="gvCurRecords_PageIndexChanging" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkDetails" runat="server" Text='Details'      NavigateUrl='<%#FormatUrl(CInt(Eval("EventID")))%>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:Gridview>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the edit template to define a label instead of a hyperlink:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lbDetails" runat="server" Text='something else' />
</EditItemTemplate>
```